# Find all integers in a string of digits which meet a criteria

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am trying to come up with an algorithm in Java which when given a string of digits can identify a combination of integers which meets the following criteria

- N = N1 + N2
- N >= N1 >= N2

```
where:
   N is the Nth element in the string or element at Nth position;
   N1 is the (N-1) element in the string & N2 is the (N-2) element in the string.

Example 1: 224610
Elements in this string are 2, 2, 4, 6, 10.
First Set:     2+2=4 (N2=2; N1=2 & N= 4);
Second Set: 2+4=6 (N2=2; N1=4 & N=6);
Third Set:    4+6=10 (N2=4; N1=6 & N= 10)

Example 2: 11112233558
Elements in this string are 1, 11, 12, 23, 35, 58

Example 3: 1101102203
Elements in this string are 1, 101, 102, 203.
```

I have already written a function which can take an ArrayList of integers and tell you whether the array complies with the requirements.

```
public static boolean complies(ArrayList<Integer> al)
{
     boolean result = true;
     int alsize = al.size();

     for (int n = alsize-1; n > 1; n--)
     {
         int N1 = al.get(n-1);
         int N2 = al.get(n-2);
         int N = al.get(n);
         if (N != ( N1 + N2))
            result  = false;
         if ((N < N1) || (N1 <  N2))
            result  = false;
     }
     return(result);
}
```

The part I am struggling with his finding an elegant way to identify all possible integer combinations which I can run through the above function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Generate all possible combinations of a given List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935315/java-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-a-given-list)

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard I would not say this is a duplicate... as there is room for new ideas to be brought up specific to this scenario, but a good reference nonetheless!

Comment: Two questions: Are you looking such that the entire list fits the requirements, or is it satisfactory for parts of a list to fit the rules. Also, the examples you give are ascending lists, does this have to be the case? (Which, if the answer to the first question is the entire list, I guess that means yes)

Comment: Since the integers are digits (non negatives), if n = n1 + n2 then n >= n1 and n >= n2. So you just need to check n = n1 + n2 and n1 >= n2.

Comment: @snickers10m  Yes, the entire list needs to fit the requirements and yes it does have to be an ascending list in order to meet the second requirement as you pointed out.

Comment: Hi All, I am not sure the referenced topic addresses my problem. In my scenario, I do not want combinations in which the digits are moved around. I want to keep the digits in the same sequence and position but grouped into various combinations of multi-digit integers.

Comment: @Urbanite you just need to determine the first two numbers, and the rest of the sequence are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about the question you asked, which was essentially how to find all the combinations of a set of digits in the order the digits were given, and realized that this could be solved recursively. All you have to do is add the first digit to all the combinations that can be made with the rest of the digits as well as put that digit in front of the first term of all the combinations. The base case is that there is only one digit, which means there is of course only one combination.

Let me give an example. With the digits 123 first we find all the combinations for 23 and since 23 has more than one digit we find all the combos for 3, which is just 3. Then add 2 to that combination which makes 2, 3 and put 2 in front of the first term of that combination, which makes 23. Now add 1 to all the combos which makes 1, 2, 3 and 1, 23 and put 1 in front of the first term which makes 12, 3 and 123.

So I made this method to find all the combinations. It returns a two dimensional arrayList with each individual arrayList being a unique combination. The preconditions are that you have to give it a string of numbers only and no empty strings. If I made a mistake or it doesn't work for your application say something. I am pretty sure you could just go through the two dimensional arrayList and check if each arrayList works in your boolean method. You can test it [here](http://ideone.com/e.js/IZCu7y%22%20type=%22text/javascript).

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> findCombos(String input) 
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> answer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    if(input.length()==1)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> combo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        answer.add(combo);
        combo.add(Integer.parseInt(input));  //this method converts from a string to an int
        return answer;
    }
    else
    {
        answer = findCombos(input.substring(1));
        int size = answer.size();  //you need to save this because when you add things to an arrayList the size changes
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) //this copies the arrayList back to itself
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<Integer>(answer.get(i));
            answer.add(copy);
        }
        int digit = (char)(input.charAt(0)-'0');//this saves the current digit
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)//this adds the digit in front of all the previous combos
            answer.get(i).add(0, digit);
        for(int i=size;i<answer.size();i++)//this puts the digit in front of the first term of the previous combos
        {
            String copy = "" + answer.get(i).get(0);//I just did this to find the length of the first term easily
            int append = (int)(digit*Math.pow(10, copy.length()));
            answer.get(i).set(0, append+answer.get(i).get(0));
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code below works against all 3 given input, and is solid enough.

```
    public class IntFinder
    {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        private static String given = "444444889321420";
        static N1N2 temp = new N1N2(given);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            N1N2 n1 = new N1N2(given);
            N1N2 n2 = new N1N2(given);

            /*IntFinder.setGiven("224610");
            n1 = new N(IntFinder.getGiven());
            n2 = new N(IntFinder.getGiven());
            n1.setValue(0, 0); // 2
            n2.setValue(1, 1); // 2*/

            /*IntFinder.setGiven("11112233558");
            n1 = new N(IntFinder.getGiven());
            n2 = new N(IntFinder.getGiven());
            n1.setValue(0, 0); // 1
            n2.setValue(1, 2); // 11*/

            IntFinder.setGiven("1101102203");
            n1 = new N1N2(IntFinder.getGiven());
            n2 = new N1N2(IntFinder.getGiven());
            n1.setValue(0, 0); // 1
            n2.setValue(1, 3); // 101

            System.out.println("string: " + n1.getValue());
            System.out.println("string: " + n2.getValue());
            System.out.println("result: " + ((IntFinder.findTillEndByN1N2(n1, n2) > -1) ? "found" : "NOT found"));
        }

        public static String setGiven(String givenString)
        {
            return IntFinder.given = givenString;
        }

        public static String getGiven()
        {
            return IntFinder.given;
        }

        public static int findTillEndByN1N2(N1N2 n1, N1N2 n2)
        {
            int retVal = -1, lenChange = n1.getLength() + n2.getLength() + n1.getStartIndex();

            retVal = findNagainstN1N2(n1, n2, lenChange);

            if (IntFinder.getGiven().length() == (n2.getEndIndex() + 1)) // base case 1 (last digit reached)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (IntFinder.getGiven().length() < (n2.getEndIndex() + 1))
            {
                System.out.println("fatal err:");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            if (retVal > -1) // recurse till end
            {
                if (!temp.getUsed())
                {
                    temp = IntFinder.shallowCopy(n1);
                    temp.setUsed(true);
                }
                n1 = IntFinder.shallowCopy(n2);
                n2.setValue(n2.getEndIndex() + 1 , retVal);
                System.out.println("string: "+n2.getValue());
                retVal = findTillEndByN1N2(n1, n2);
            }
            else
                return retVal;
            return retVal;
        }

        public static Integer findNagainstN1N2(N1N2 n1, N1N2 n2, Integer startIndex)
        {
            String remainingGiven = IntFinder.getGiven().substring(startIndex);
            Integer i, n1n2Total = 0, retVal = -1;
            n1n2Total = n1.getValue() + n2.getValue();
            for (i = 0; i < remainingGiven.length(); i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    int found = Integer.parseInt(remainingGiven.substring(0, (i+1)));


                    if (found == n1n2Total)
                    {
                        retVal = startIndex + i;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (found > n1n2Total)
                    {
                        retVal = -1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    ;
                } 
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        public static N1N2 shallowCopy(N1N2 from) {
            N1N2 newN = new N1N2(IntFinder.getGiven());
            newN.setValue(from.getStartIndex(), from.getEndIndex());
            return newN;
        }
    }


>>N1N2.class

    public class N1N2 {
        private String givenString;
        private int startIndex = 0;
        private int endIndex = -1;
        private int value = 0;
        private int length = endIndex + 1;
        private Boolean used = false;

        public N1N2(String given) {
            startIndex = 0;
            endIndex = given.length() - 1;
            givenString = given;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public int getLength() {
            return length;
        }

        public Boolean getUsed()
        {
            return used;
        }

        public void setUsed(Boolean used)
        {
            this.used = used;
        }

    //    public void outValues()
    //    {
    //        System.out.println("given:" + givenString + ", startIndex:"+ startIndex + ", endIndex: " + endIndex + ", length:" + length + ", value:" + value + "\n");
    //    }

        public void setValue(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
            this.value = Integer.parseInt(givenString.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1));
            this.startIndex = startIndex;
            this.endIndex = endIndex;
            this.length = (this.value + "").length();
    //        this.outValues();
        } 

        public int getEndIndex() {
            return this.endIndex;
        }

        public int getStartIndex() {
            return this.startIndex;
        }
    }
```

> Just set n1 and n2 properly before calling IntFinder.findTillEndByN1N2(n1, n2).
>
> Observe the examples I used.
>
> So to complete the program, create your own algorithm using two loops filling
>
> n1.setValues and n2.setValues
>
> Ex.

```
given = 1232447
//first loop
n1.setValues(0,0) // value = 1
n2.setValues(1,1) // value = 2
IntFinder.findTillEndByN1N2(n1, n2) // returns -1 // not found...

//next loop - increment n2 length
n1.setValues(0,0) // value = 1
n2.setValues(1,2) // value = 23
IntFinder.findTillEndByN1N2(n1, n2) // returns 1 // now found till end.


//ofcourse when n2 reached the last digit, increment n1 length by 1 and set n2 length back to 1.

//for given=444444889321420 // 44 444 488 932 1420
//all findTillEnd with n1 length 1 should fail so inc n1 length on outer loop
//n1.setValue(0, 1) // 2 digit number ( 44)
//n2.setValue(0, 0) // 4

//upon continuing loop, the desired result will be met.
```

Answer (score 0):

In line with the above  solution from Pham I could modify the code to exclude the edge cases and create a solution for the above question.This method will always return true if it complies with the pattern else false  and yes we have to find first two elements to make it work.Checked for all test cases :

```
public static boolean complies(String input){
    // List<Long> firstTwo = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for(int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            long first = Long.parseLong(input.substring(0, j + 1));//substring form 0 to j
            long second = Long.parseLong(input.substring(j + 1, i + 1));//substring from j + 1 to i
            if(second < first)
                  continue;

            String last = "" + first + second;
            System.out.println("first :"+first+" second :"+second);
            if(last.length() == input.length()){
                return false;
            }
           // firstTwo.add(first);
           // firstTwo.add(second);
            while(last.length() < input.length()){
                  long nxt = first + second;
                  last += nxt;
                  first = second;
                  second = nxt;
            } 
            if(last.equals(input)){//Matched!
                System.out.println("matched");
                // dont go further return true
                return true;
            }
           // firstTwo.clear();
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```